# Error: Output Argument Not Assigned During Call

Tags: matlab

Here's my code for a k-nearest neighbors algorithm:

```
function [preds, distances, indices] = knnfull(HandTrain,HandTest)
    nn_value = 10; % how many nearest      
    inputs = HandTrain(:,2:end);
    Y = HandTrain(:,1); 
    [preds, distances, indices] = knn_alg(inputs, y, HandTest, nn_value);
end

function [preds, D, I] = knn_alg(train_inputs, train_y, test_inputs, nn_value)
    num_train_inputs = size(train_inputs,2);
    num_train_examples = size(train_inputs,1)
    num_test_inputs = size(test_inputs,2);
    num_test_examples = size(test_inputs,1)
    preds = zeros(size(test_inputs,1),1);
    [D,I] = pdist2(train_inputs,test_inputs,'euclidean','Smallest',nn_value);
    preds = mode(train_y(I'),2);
end
```

If you're asking why I have two separate functions, that's a good question. But regardless, I'm getting the errors:

> `Error in knnkaggle>knn_alg (line 16)
>
>   num_train_inputs = size(train_inputs,2);
>
>   
>
>   Output argument "indices" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to 
>
>   "C:...knn_alg".
>
>   
>
>   Error in knnkaggle (line 10)
>
>   [preds, distances, indices] = knn_alg(inputs, y, HandTest, nn_value);`

Can't figure out the issue.

Comment: My guess would be that `pdist2` returns prematurely without assigning anything to `I`, hence the error. Can you put `I = 0` before calling `pdist2`, and then printing `I`'s value before and after `pdist2`?

Comment: Can you tell what `knnkaggle` is, and which lines the error messages correspond?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that there are possible paths through your function which don't assign any value at all to the output argument.

Comment: How is that possible though given the code above?  I always assign a value to the three parameters.