# Error in Matlab, calling a function

Tags: matlab, function

The errors are:

Error in getvalues (line 4)
faceNoNoise = wiener2(x, [5 5]);

Output argument "mouthTall" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "C:\Users\Trent\face\getvalues.m>getvalues".

Error in finalProject2 (line 10)
[ numWhiteEyebrow, mouthTall, eyebrowHeight ] = getvalues( faceGray )

```
faceNoNoise = wiener2(x, [5 5]); <---- getvalues.m  line with error

function finalProject2(x)       <----- finalproject file

face = imread(x);
faceGray = rgb2gray(face);

numWhiteEyebrow = 0;
mouthTall = 0;
eyebrowHeight = 0;

[ numWhiteEyebrow, mouthTall, eyebrowHeight ] = getvalues( faceGray ) <--error above

end
```

Im trying to figure out why its doing this...

Comment: need to c the getValues.m file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens since you have not assigned required output values in the function `getvalues.m`. There are 3 output arguments which should be returned by `getvalues.m`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227564/error-output-argument-not-assigned-during-call) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FA99V6/index.html). To clarify even more, if your function definition in `getvalues.m` file is `[a,b,c]=getvalues(x)` (and this is how it would mostly be in your case) then in your `getvalue.m` file, you should have variables `a`, `b` and `c`.